# how to use mesh geometrical information to connect selected points?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Now I try to connect points on the mesh that are selected by the user. Currently I use spline function from VTK to connect points. However the curve is expected to run along the ridge on the mesh. I search over the internet, but don't obtain any useful information. Can anyone provide some helpful paper or links?

Regards

Jogging Song

Comment: Imagine I try to remove one ear of Stanford bunny. I hope to select a few points around the ear and one method can find the accurate positions that separate the ear from the body from selected points. Currently I plan to form one poly line from selected points. More points will be selected on line segments of the poly line because selected points are not enough. For each points the closest points on the mesh will be found, then I will obtain one dense poly line one the mesh. Active contour method such as snake or level set will be used to evolve the poly line to expected position.

Comment: As I understand, you want to join mesh vertices selected by the user. If it is so, I assume that a shortest path algorithm between two points will do. Somethink like Dijkstra's http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights

Comment: However, the obtained path may not correspond to the boundary because the selected points are sparse and not positioned accurately. I plan to use active contour to evolve the initial lien to the expected position where the curvature is high.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what you are asking ? An initial guess of the ridge path, based on input points, that you can feed to an active contour ? If not, rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes. Sorry to repeat the problem. I have littler experience with active contour. I am not sure this is a good idea and hope to get some comments. Is there any better idea to solve the problem?

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no well defined place to do a cut. If your goal is to get an ear, I think it doesn't matter. A shortest path will be no better nor worse than other approaches. If the goal is to create a one-eared rabbit, then you will need to somehow fill and smooth the hole surface after the cut to make it unnoticeable.